# Spring interceptor that is activated post handling but the response is not yet commited

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, interceptor

In our project we have many controllers that receives responses and respond with @responseBody. We would like to have an interceptor that is capable of changing the response headers right after the controllers returned an object.

We tried to create such interceptor but the response is already commited for it and it cannot really re-set the header response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried ??

Comment: i wanna know too. Headers with responseBody can be changed with RequesMapping annotation, like 'produce = "application/json"'. Or you can add ServletReponse for you method and add headers.